# JQuery highlight effect on text box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'd like to create the highlight/fade effect as demonstrated at:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

However, I'm trying to perform the highlight on a text box (in IE) rather than a div, as follows:

```
$("#myInput").effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
```

I have the required effects.core.js and effects.highlight.js files included.

Is this scenario supported?  If not, is there an alternative plugin that accomplishes what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/96gKQ/

Comment: Strange.  Since I restarted my browser, it's working for me now as well.  I'm guessing something in IE went astray (hard to believe).  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damien-at-SF was correct.  It eventually worked for me too.  I'm thinking IE went off in the weeds and then worked after I restarted it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [jquery.highlight-3](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html). It's quite easy to use.

Comment: Looks like I'm ok with my original approach, but thanks for the suggestion.  Pretty cool plugin!